# How to run tasks in parallel in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, parallel-processing

Unless I've grossly misunderstood MSBuild, tasks are executed in the document order in which they appear within a 'Target' node.

I'd like to be able to specify that two tasks (such as xcopy tasks) could run in parallel. I was expecting there to be a 'Parallel' task or something...?

Comment: vote for it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/9604311-allow-custom-build-tools-to-run-in-parallel

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As was stated, you cannot parallelise at the task level or even at the target level. MSBuild only will build **projects** (i.e. MSBuild project files) in parallel. So you have to use the [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) with multiple projects specified and the *BuildInParallel* attribute should be set to true. Also make sure that when the build is invoked on the command line that the /m switch is sent it.

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Comment: I think visual studio (msbuild) already compile files in parallel, even inside one project.

Comment: @BaiyanHuang: I think that's the CL task being able to compile several files in parallel but there's nothing in MSBuild that allows you to use that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 39):

Try the new parallel task in the MSBuild Extension Pack - http://mikefourie.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/executing-msbuild-targets-in-parallel-part-1

Answer (score 12):

MSBuild has a `/m` command line switch to tell it the maximum number of concurrent processes to build with. The default value is 1. `/m:x` will use x processes. `/m` will use the number of processors on computer.

I've used this as part of a shortcut in Visual Studio to run builds quicker by compiling projects in parallel. Scott Hanselman has a few posts about it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in introducing explicit parallelism at the Task level; this works only for non-dependent MSBuild projects as far as I can see. I'll perhaps see if I can transform the tasks into separate projects.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of a way to run msbuild targets in parallel. The idea is same ... presenting this msbuild file itself as a project to build. I copied it from my own question: [Evaluate item defined in msbuild task via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459302/evaluate-item-defined-in-msbuild-task-via-c-sharp)

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="PrepareEnvironmentForBuild;MapDrives">
    <Exec Command="$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild /nologo /clp:Verbosity=quiet $(MSBuildThisFileFullPath) /t:TargetWithConfidentialSteps"/>
    <ItemGroup>
        <StepsToRunInParallel Include="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)">
            <Properties>TargetToInvoke=ParallelTarget1</Properties>
        </StepsToRunInParallel>
        <StepsToRunInParallel Include="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)">
            <Properties>TargetToInvoke=ParallelTarget2</Properties>
        </StepsToRunInParallel>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(StepsToRunInParallel)" BuildInParallel="true" StopOnFirstFailure="true" Targets="InvokeInParallelWithinThisProject"/>

</Target>
<Target Name="InvokeInParallelWithinThisProject">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)" Targets="$(TargetToInvoke)" StopOnFirstFailure="true"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="ParallelTarget1">
    <Message Text="Hello from ParallelTarget1"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="ParallelTarget2">
    <Message Text="Hello from ParallelTarget2"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="PrepareEnvironmentForBuild">
    <Message Text="Hello from PrepareEnvironmentForBuild"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="MapDrives">
    <Message Text="Hello from MapDrives"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="TargetWithConfidentialSteps">
    <Message Text="Hush! Verbosity on the wrapper does not affect the Exec call." Importance="High"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Remember to call MSBuild.exe with the `/m`flag... I didn't and was disappointed that it didn't build in parallel...

Comment: Your script seems to work but somehow my <PropertyGroup> values do not get passed on to the msbuild exe you spawn. Is there a way to pass on all these values?

Comment: Sorry @ikku100. Haven't used MSBuild for several years now :-(

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to do this other than using some external tool.  I suspect this is because this introduces potential dependency problems that MS chooses to ignore for the time being, allowing external tool vendors to tackle the problem (and charge quite a bit of money for it).

Answer (score 0):

For C++, you can do it with

- ```
   <MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>
  ```

Which can be found if you search 'multi' under `C++ > All Options` of the Property pages of the project

More info here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/recommendations-to-speed-c-builds-in-visual-studio/