# Why is CMake-CDT4-NMake-Build so slow?

Tags: eclipse, visual-c++, cmake

I am compiling the OpenCascade Community Edition (https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/) on Windows 7. The build files are generated with CMake 2.8.8.

When I use the "Visual Studio 10" generater and compile the projekt with msbuild from a console the whole build process takes 17 minutes. On the other hand, if I select "Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles" and start the build process in Eclipse, it takes 87 minutes.

Does anyone know the reason for this difference? Is there a way to make the Eclipse build much faster?

With msbuild I do NOT use parallel builds. Also when I take a look at the task manager it seems as if the CPU usage of both build processes is nearly the same.

I have searched a lot, but did not find any clue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VS IDE projects do parallel builds.  nmake does not.   One think you could try is jom or some other tool, see here for information:
  http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/434

I did not notice that you said msbuild is not doing parallel.  How did you do that?  It will be default do parallel target builds.

Comment: As far as I know msbuild can not do a parallel build of one project, it can only build independent projects simultaneously: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997047/how-to-run-tasks-in-parallel-in-msbuild). Please check your task manager! For my builds the CPU usage percentage number shows, that my builds use only one CPU.

Comment: Yes, you are correct msbuild does parallel at the target level and if you only have one target it will not be parallel.  Not sure why nmake is so slow for you.  However, you might want to try jom and see if it speeds things up.  It is a simple download and you can run jom in a nmake build tree with no changes.  Might be a good data point.